# uninstall ubuntu laptop

Tags: grub2, uninstall

I had ubuntu as a dual boot on my laptop.

I wanted to install a fresh copy of ubuntu and delete the partition on windows and reclaimed it as a new storage location.

I then downloaded the windows installer for ubuntu 12.04 lts.

I noticed that before i installed ubuntu 12.04lts when I turn on my laptop it still gives me the option to boot into ubuntu (despite me deleting the partition and reclaiming the memory). I have been trying to boot straight into windows but to no avail.

Anyway, I have tried installing ubuntu 12.04lts with the windows installer 3 times and all 3 times my machine would just freeze at the ubuntu log in. When I force shut down and restart it says that grub cannot be found.

Can someone please help....

Answer (score 0):

Use liveCD , 'try ubuntu' mode go and check your GParted ;)

If your want just overwrite everything and install fresh version of Ubuntu - just delete everything and use GUI installer - easy

or

printout here 'df -l' ( from terminal )

Comment: I have deleted the partition so I cannot go back onto ubuntu.

I installed it with wubi and I have also uninstalled that.

I am now trying to use wubi to install 12.04 but I believe there are some issues with the windows installer. 

I will try one more time, if it still does not work I will try and get 11.10 through wubi again. Failing that I will have to use a partition .....

Comment: what wubi installer does it installs big file on your NTFS ( windows ) file system - what is used to run your ubuntu OS. That makes your ubuntu work slower with worse performance and 100% dependable on your windows os.

Comment: You can also check this blogpost with screenshots http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/